# Overiding the colour and size of the SplitPane divider on JavaFX8 isn't working using CSS3

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to change the colour of the divider to plain really thin black line and I am using the following CSS but it is not working:

```
.split-pane-divider {
-fx-border-style: solid;
-fx-border-width: 1px;
-fx-background-color: black;
}
```

This is what shows instead:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
.split-pane-divider {
    -fx-padding: 0 1 0 1 ;
    -fx-background-color: black ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was to do with the default padding, it should look like this:

```
.split-pane-divider {
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```